# How to enable multiple selection from contact list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-contacts

I am able to make user select 1 contact from the contacts list, it gives me name & phone number of user, but i need to make user select multiple contacts from the same contact list.

This is my code.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACTS_RESULT_CODE)
```

**OnActivityResult()**

```
    if(requestCode == CONTACTS_RESULT_CODE){

        var phoneNo: String? = null
        var name: String? = null

        val uri: Uri = data!!.getData()
        val cursor: Cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val phoneIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
            val nameIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
            phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex)
            name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
            Log.e("onActivityResult()", "$phoneIndex $phoneNo $nameIndex $name")


            val invitesModel = InvitesModel()
            invitesModel.contactName= name
            invitesModel.contactNumber= phoneNo.replace(" ", "")
            contactsList?.add(invitesModel)
        }
        cursor.close()



      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no official way of getting multiple contacts picked in Android using an Intent.

The only two ways to achieve this is either repeatedly call single `phone-picker` until the user signals they selected enough contacts, or obtaining `READ_CONTACTS` permission from the user, and showing a list of contacts to be multiple-picked in your own app.

Having said that, I see in your code that you're trying to implement an invite flow, that was until recently easily available from Firebase using [`Firebase Invites`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites) but is now deprecated in favor of [`Firebase Dynamic Links`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) with the use-case of [inviting users to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/user-to-user), see the [migration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/deprecation) docs to understand how that could work.